# Restore Classic layout to Apple Mail

Tags: mail.app

Currently Apple Mail displays like the following.

[image]

I would like apple mail on my Apple Mail on 11.5 to display like the following similar to the Gmail web client.  I would like a list view like the following image of an older version of Apple Mail.

How to I achieve this?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get the Classic view back in Apple Mail:

- Go to **Preferences**
- Select **Viewing**
- Tick the **Use classic layout** checkbox

[image: Apple Mail Preferences Viewing Classic Layout]

Answer (score 3):

Under Monterey it's **View** > **Use Column Layout**

https://support.apple.com/en-nz/guide/mail/mlhlc18e666f/mac

[image]